# Repeated calling of Mathematica function from R through system call make it extremely slow

Tags: bugs, interoperability, r

I have the following simple function in test.wls file

```
x = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]]
y = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[3]]]
z = x+y
Print[z]
```

I call the function sequentially 500 times through R

```
mycount = 1

for (i in 1:500){
  command1 = './test.wls 1 2'
  system(command1, intern = T)
  print(mycount)
  mycount=mycount+1
}
```

After 234 calls, it takes a long time to get to the next call. Is there a limit to how frequently one is allowed to make system calls?

Comment: Maybe there's some problem with memory cleanup? Have you tried checking RAM usage during this evaluation using the system resource monitor?